# RetryTemplate Working in local But not working on UAT server

Tags: spring-boot

I am using RetryTemplate of spring boot i am trying hit third party URL if not able to connect then i want to retry.it is working in local machine as expected but if i deployed my application on UAT and tried for retry it working but it retries more then mentioned maxattempts and at the end it giving 504 bad_gateway exception without any response on swagger?
any one help me in this

```
retryTemplate.execute(arg0 -> {
                    log.error("Sending Company Request to SIRA.");
                    final String xmlResponse = submitPayload(request, ResponseTimer, Client);
                    final ScreeningResponse screeningResponseFromXml = resultMapper
                            .getScreeningResponseFromXml(soapRequestXml, xmlResponse, screeningProvider, sourceDataId);
                    if (!screeningResponseFromXml.getErrors().isEmpty()
                            && Arrays.asList(SiraRetryableFaultCode.values()).toString()
                            .contains(screeningResponseFromXml.getErrors().stream().findFirst().get().getCode())) {
                        throw new FraudFaultCodeException(screeningResponseFromXml.getErrors().stream().findFirst().get().getCode(),
                                sourceDataId, screeningResponseFromXml.getErrors().stream().findFirst().get().getMessage());
                    }
                    return screeningResponseFromXml;
                });
```

========my retry config file====

```
@Configuration
public class RetryAppConfig {

    @Bean
    public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
        FixedBackOffPolicy fixedBackOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
        fixedBackOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(2000L);
        retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(fixedBackOffPolicy);
        ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy exRetryPolicy = new ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy();
        exRetryPolicy.setPolicyMap(new HashMap<Class<? extends Throwable>, RetryPolicy>() {
            {
                put(RetryableException.class, new SimpleRetryPolicy(5));
                put(FraudFaultCodeException.class, new SimpleRetryPolicy(5));
            }
        });
        retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(exRetryPolicy);
        return retryTemplate;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no way to tell without seeing your code.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki--please check i have added some part of code

Comment: hI @Sushant, We need more code than this. You mention that retry is happening more than usual as well, but we cannot see the retry configuration. Can you try to simulate the request on the server to see if it is possible to reach?

Comment: @Brother-please check my config file apart from this i haven't made any changes on server its retrying but more then what i mentioned in simpleretry i.e.5 times and at the end it showing 504 bad_gateway in swagger